# MacBook Pro 2015 install app on external drive including a cloud storage drive

Tags: mac, macos, usb, ms-office

I would like to install MS Office 2016 on my MacBook Pro but there's not enough space. I thought of installing it on an external USB drive. However, I got an error message that "Microsoft Office 2016 can't be installed on this disk. OS X isn't installed.", and hence I couldn't install it.
Is there anyhow to overcome this situation?
I have one more question which is, is it possible to consider a cloud storage drive like Google Drive as a kind of USB and install an app on it?

[image: The message I got]

Comment: I got same issue above..
Can't install app on External and my Internal is almost filed up.. Can remove anything so I can install MS office in internal and then transfer to external because I got totally no additional App on my MACBook, but is getting filled up.
Wish I can get assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Install the application to Macintosh HD (your internal drive). Then go to your Applications folder, move the applications (after they've been installed) to the external drive. Test to make sure the apps on the drive open properly. Then delete the ones in the Applications folder.

Addition: if you have a cloud storage service, you cannot install the apps onto it, but you can store some of your other documents there while you install MS Office on your internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. The very fact that it requires you to go through the install procedure means that there is more going on than just a file being copied over to your Applications folder. Things are being installed in your systems folders, which is the reason why you need to select a drive with Mac OS X installed.

If you were to do as @NoahL said in his answer, the program would only run on computers where the installer had been run in the past.

Comment: I believe that's the point. The point (I would guess, judging based on the picture) is not to install the apps on many computers, but to install it only on this one. The reason to NOT install it on the internal drive is that the internal drive is tiny (128GB) and has almost no space left (<4.5GB free).

Comment: @NoahL I suppose but the thing is is that the bulk of the files are installed into system folders so it would be futile to put just the launcher on a USB.

Comment: If the app will work only on the Mac it was installed on originally that will be sufficient for me. I just want to overcome the problem of low disk space not to use the app universally via my USB.

Comment: @NoahL you're right, I need to install MS Office which requires around 7.3GB disk space.

Comment: @Mina move some files to the flash drive to free up the space, then follow my instructions, then return the files to the internal drive. Alternatively, get a larger storage internal drive (see Other World Computing, www.macsales.com)

Comment: The problem erupted when I installed Parallels Desktop which is really massive. I'm thinking of simply moving it to the USB (as it's already installed) and then use the free space to install MS Office normally. Do you think it's a good idea? (You have any idea if 15GB of the USB will be enough to Parallels?

Answer (score -2):

You can!!(this mite not work but give it a try!!)
just get a copy of mac os and get it on the dics and then get the app you want!
Thanks